# What is the difference between column reducing a matrix and computing its inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra

I read in a paper that column reducing a matrix of polynomials takes $\tilde{O}(n^{\omega}d)$, where $d$ is the max degree of the polynomials, and $\omega$ is the exponent of integer matrix multiplication.  However, computing its inverse takes $\tilde{O}(n^3 d)$.  Why don't these take the same amount of time?  Can't you create the inverse of a matrix at the same time that you're column reducing it?

Edit: these were two different papers.  But the paper about the inverse said that $\tilde{O}(n^3 d)$ was a lower bound.